# Geocordinate class in Windows silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, maps

I have just started working with Map control in windows silverlight 8.1 app
I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_converting) link, but facing an error in CoordinateConverter Class 
 as

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'

on line

> geocoordinate.Altitude ?? Double.NaN

Please tell me whats this? for what purpose this ?? operator is used. And what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code compiles just fine on my end, make sure you included the correct namespaces that are on tutorial.

---

To answer your other question with the `??` :

The `??` is just a fancy if state for Nullable Types

For example

```
int? x = null;   // notice the ? after the "int"

// Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise,
// if x = null, set y to -1.
int y = x ?? -1;
```

so in the tutorial they are just converting a `Geocoordinate` to a `GeoCoordinate` by creating a new `GeoCoordinate` with the values of the
the `Geocoordinate`.

...

```
geocoordinate.Altitude ?? Double.NaN;
```

...

means if the argument is not NULL then use the `geocoordinate.Altitude` otherwise use `Double.Nan` when creating the new object.

Comment: ok..Thank you.. I checked my code I was passing  object of GeoCoordinate as parameter, instead of Geocoordinate.